# autodesk forge Transcoding has been stuck in 66%

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am an autodesk forge developer, and now I am uploading a rvt file, but translating the source file into SVF format has been trapped in 66% for two days

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYD3M.png)

[my rvt file](http://pan.baidu.com/s/1dEFewdb)

Answer (score 0):

The process did failed (stuck) with this model. After diagnosis by the engineer team, it looks like an issue with the specific model. It has been logged. The workaround is [publish views] , select some views in Revit and save this model. translate again and the process can succeed.